# Tesseract training archieves a worse result than without training

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I used the Windows installer of tesseract-ocr 3.02.02 (I didn't find a newer one for 3.04). My image is a JPEG with a resolution of 600dpi (3507x4960) which is a scanned blank "certificate of incapacity for work". The OCR result without training is much more accurate than after training. So what am I doing wrong?

This way I build my box file:

```
SET LANG=arbeitsunfaehigkeit
SET FONTNAME=hausarzt
SET TESSLANG=%LANG%.%FONTNAME%.exp0

tesseract %TESSLANG%.jpg %TESSLANG% -l deu batch.nochop makebox
```

Using jTessBoxEditor I fixed every box by hand. Then I started the training:

```
SET LANG=arbeitsunfaehigkeit
SET FONTNAME=hausarzt
SET TESSLANG=%LANG%.%FONTNAME%.exp0

tesseract %TESSLANG%.jpg %TESSLANG% -l deu nobatch box.train

unicharset_extractor %TESSLANG%.box

shapeclustering -F font_properties -U unicharset %TESSLANG%.tr

mftraining -F font_properties -U unicharset -O %LANG%.unicharset %TESSLANG%.tr

cntraining %TESSLANG%.tr

MOVE inttemp %LANG%.inttemp
MOVE normproto %LANG%.normproto
MOVE pffmtable %LANG%.pffmtable
MOVE shapetable %LANG%.shapetable

combine_tessdata %LANG%.

COPY %LANG%.traineddata %TESSERACT_HOME%\tessdata /Y
```

The OCR without training (archieving the best results) is done like:

```
SET LANG=arbeitsunfaehigkeit
SET FONTNAME=hausarzt
SET TESSLANG=%LANG%.%FONTNAME%.exp0

tesseract %TESSLANG%.jpg without_training -l deu
```

Using the traineddata:

```
SET LANG=arbeitsunfaehigkeit
SET FONTNAME=hausarzt
SET TESSLANG=%LANG%.%FONTNAME%.exp0

tesseract %TESSLANG%.jpg with_training -l %LANG%
```

Maybe I am wrong but I expect a perfect result (I use the same JPEG for training and OCRing).

Here the first part of without_training.txt:

```
Paul Albrechts Verlag, 22952 Lütjensee Bei verspäteter Vorlage droht Krankengeldverlust!

Krankenkasse bzw. Kostenträger

Name, Vorname des Versicherten

geb. am

Kassen—Nr. Versicherten—Nr. Status

Betriebsstätten-Nr. Arzt—Nr. Datum
```

And the first part of with_training.txt:

```
Pau/A/brechrs Ver/ag, 22952 Lüfjensee Be! verspäteter vor!age droht Krankenge!dver!ust!

Krankenkasse bzw. Kostenträger

Name, Vorname des Versicherten

geb. am

Kassen-Nr. Versicherten-Nr. status

Betriebsstätten-Nr. Arzt-Nr. Datum
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding the language "deu" did the trick:

```
tesseract %TESSLANG%.jpg with_training -l %LANG%+deu
```

instead of

```
tesseract %TESSLANG%.jpg with_training -l %LANG%
```

Comment: Hi... are you sure by adding language, your trained model was in effect? I feel the deu model took preference